# Python time of trying to open page with opener

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to open multiple pages using threading. When I use a single thread, all is OK, but when using two or more threads, I receive a timeout response.  My code:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
page = opener.open(url).read()
```

Could it be that I need to specify a timeout for waiting on the opening of a page?

Comment: How to make the attempt to open the page? It opens, but with a delay.

Comment: `import socket
       import urllib2

       # timeout in seconds
       timeout = 10
       socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

       # this call to urllib2.urlopen now uses the default timeout
       # we have set in the socket module
       req = urllib2.Request(url)
       response = urllib2.urlopen(req)` This don't work

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a separate opener in each thread.  Example from the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://www.example.com:3128/'})

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
# This time, rather than install the OpenerDirector, we use it directly:
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```

The problem with `urllib2.install_opener` is that `opener` object is shared between all the threads and this may cause concurrency problems (as in your case).

Comment: I need cookies to open url

Comment: @MikkiNorman `ProxyHandler` is used only as example here.  I believe you are capable of replacing it with cookie processor :)

Comment: @MikkiNorman `urllib2.install_opener(opener)` replaces previously added opener, so you are using the same object in all threads.

Comment: @MikkiNorman Nope.  If you have further questions/concerns, please expand your original question.

Comment: I'm trying mechanize, opener.open, urlopen, Request... Nothing resolve my problem. One thread - all is ok, two or more - many timeout's.  But one month ago - all's work excellent.